# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

Tags: laravel

I want to display the article using pagination in the blade but I get the following error.
I have no problem without using pagination.

> BadMethodCallException Method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View:
> c:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\frontend\tag.blade.php)

```php
    public function tag($slug)
    {
        $tag = Tag::where('slug', $slug)->first() ?? abort(404);
        $articles =  Article::where('status', '=', '1')->paginate(5);
        $article = $tag->articles;
        return view('frontend.tag', compact('article'));
    }
```

**frontend/tag.blade.php:**

```php
    {{ $article->links() }}
```

**Model: Article.php**

```php
     public function articles()
      {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
      }
```

Comment: You'd call the method l**inks** on the collection ``$articles->links()`` , not on the single object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling incorrectly. It should be `$article->links()` not `article->links()` in your blade.You have missed `$` in `article`

```
 {{ $article->links() }}
```

Also in your controller remove  `$article = $tag->articles;` .Since this replace pagination result from first query and it should be

```
$articles =  Article::whereHas('tags',function($query)use($slug){$query->where('slug', $slug)})->where('status', '=', '1')->paginate(5);
```

Final solution would be

```
public function tag($slug)
{
    $articles =  Article::whereHas('tags',function($query)use($slug){
    $query->where('slug', $slug)})->where('status', '=', '1')->paginate(5);
              
     return view('frontend.tag', compact('article'));
}
```

In Article model add relation

```
public function tags()
      {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
      }
```

and view for pagination

```
 {{ $article->links() }}
```

Comment: with this code $article = $tag->articles; show articles related to a specific tag.        public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }

Comment: This code worked.
But does not display pagination This code  {{ $article->links() }}  is in my file but does not display pagination

Comment: show full code of controller and blade .update in question

Answer (score 0):

In you blade file, you are doing `{{ article->links() }}`. So you are using your `$article` variable like a collection

However, in your controller (the code before the blade), the `$articles` is the variable that has pagination.

You can only call `...->links()` on a Paginator (in your case, this is the `$articles` variable). You cannot call `...->links()` on a collection (in your case, `$article` is a collection -- a collection of `$tag->articles`)

Update: I am assuming you did not miss out the `$` for the `article` variable in `{{ article->links() }}`. Else, you should have received a different type of yelling (parse error)

Comment: with this code $article = $tag->articles; show articles related to a specific tag.        
   public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }

Comment: Your intentions are not clear. In `frontend/tag.blade.php`, do you want to display a paginated link of articles that have `status = 1`, or you want to display a paginated link of articles that have a tag with `slug = $slug` and `status = 1`?